# Reload JS/CSS files on change without page reloading

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, livereload

I'm using Livereload for Grunt.js to reload web-page after any of watching files are being changed.

Is it possible to delete changed js or css file from the cache and reload only them, NOT reloading the whole html-page?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005847/how-can-i-get-grunt-watch-livereload-to-reload-sass-css-without-a-full-page-refr) seems to be asked right but with no right answer. How to update file in browser cache after it is updated? Thanks.

Comment: It still reloads the whole page with Livereload. And if i turn it on and do as they say in your link, nothing happens (both if I update CSS or HTML files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it only for CSS files, using grunt-browser-sync.

This plugins allows to reload only the CSS modified file.

[Here](http://www.browsersync.io/docs/grunt/) is the documentation.

Comment: It reloads CSS and that's great, thank you! But what about JS?

Comment: Unfortunately there is not plugin to do that yet :(

Comment: You can use livereload for javascript files and browsersync to css files. I use it and its very nice :)